# How do I remove all packages from a certain repository?

Tags: package-management

For a smooth upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10, I would like to remove all packages which are not in the default repositories (e.g. chromium PPA and third-party repositories). What is the easiest way (preferably CLI) to find and remove these packages?

Edit: this question is not restricted to PPA's, I have a x2go repository as well, so I'm looking for a generic command to remove packages belonging to a certain repository. For PPA's, the question [How can PPAs be removed](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/6969) has great answers.

Comment: For those who want to remove all external packages, disable all PPAs and use http://code.google.com/p/apt-downgrade/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This script can list all packages from a particular server/branch (modifying the two declared variables):

```
#!/bin/bash

server="http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/"
branch="maverick-updates/main"

apt-cache policy $(dpkg -l | awk 'NR >= 6 { print $2 }') |
  awk -v server="$server" -v branch="$branch" \
    '/^[^ ]/      { split($1, a, ":"); pkg = a[1] }
    nextline == 1 { nextline = 0; if ($2 == server && $3 == branch) print pkg }
    /\*\*\*/      { nextline = 1 }'
```

if you need to list all packages not coming from a particular server, independently from the branch, replace the next-to-last line with:

```
nextline == 1 { nextline = 0; if ($2 != server) print pkg }
```

Comment: Not what I'm exactly looking for, this script just displays the all packages from a specific repository entry. By replacing `$2 == server && $3 == branch` by `$2 != server`, my question is answered. Please put that in your answer :) (the `branch=` line can be removed) Note: it's assumed that all packages come from a single repository server.

Comment: This script (slightly modified per my last comment) works as expected. The `libvpx0` package existed in both the main repo as in the chromium-daily PPA. After removing the repositories from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, I had still a left-over package: `libvpx0`. I "repaired" this as follows: remove the library with dpkg, ignoring dependencies: `sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=libvpx0 --remove libvpx0`. Next, install it again from the main repo: `sudo apt-get install libvpx0`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: probably you could have shortened your work with `sudo apt-get install libvpx0=$version_string`, supposing the two available packages have different version strings.

Comment: indeed, that was possible too and maybe better as well.

Comment: I just needed to check which packages are not installed from the default repos. The command `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/{print $2}') > policy.txt; awk '!/^ /{pkg=$1}check{print pkg, $2;check=0}/\*\*\*/{check=1} ' policy.txt | grep -v archive.ubuntu` is a good start  (add more `grep -v` to exclude certain PPAs). Package versions that are not known in any repo show up as `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Answer (score 22):

Check out [ppa-purge [image: Install ppa-purge]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ppa-purge).

Usage:

```
ppa-purge -purge <nameofppa> [-s hostserver]
```

Hostserver defaults to `ppa.launchpad.net`.

Here is the link to the [manpage for the `ppa-purge` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ppa-purge) for reference.

Comment: Or you could use my branch of ppa-purge which has many bug fixes and improvements over the ppa-purge in universe repository. See [here](https://launchpad.net/~jarnos/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-purge) for more information.

Answer (score 19):

## Overcoming `aptitude`'s Multiarch Bug for `ppa-purge`

Normally, as [Vadim Rutkovsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/9693/vadim-rutkovsky) and [Takkat](https://askubuntu.com/users/3940/takkat) have [explained](https://askubuntu.com/a/37541/22949), running [`ppa-purge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ppa-purge.1.html) with default syntax is an effective way to remove all packages provided by a PPA, properly downgrading them to versions provided in other configured software sources whenever possible.

However, as Takkat has pointed out, [bug 831768](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/831768) prevents `ppa-purge` from working properly to remove [multiarch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) packages (like 32-bit packages installed on 64-bit systems). This is because `aptitude` cannot handle conflicting dependencies in multiarch packages (that's what the bug is about), and the default behavior of `ppa-purge` is to use [`aptitude`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/aptitude.8.html) to downgrade packages.

**Fortunately, `ppa-purge` accepts the `-i` flag which causes it to prefer `apt-get` to `aptitude` as its backend.** As documented in the bug report, using `apt-get` is an effective alternative to manually invoking `aptitude`, so running `ppa-purge` with the `-i` flag ***should* be an effective workaround for removing/downgrading all packages provided by a PPA, including multiarch packages**.

## How To Do It

Here's the syntax:

```
sudo ppa-purge -i ppa:ppaowner/ppaname
```

As usual (same as when the `-i` flag is not used):

- **`ppaowner`** is replaced with the owner of the PPA.
- *`/ppaname`* is optional. If present, ***`ppaname`*** is replaced with the name of the PPA. If not, it defaults to `ppa`.

*For example*, suppose I had the [PPA for unstable builds of qBittorrent](https://launchpad.net/~hydr0g3n/+archive/qbittorrent-unstable) installed, and I wanted to remove it completely, automatically downgrading qBittorrent to whatever version is available through my other software sources *using `apt-get` behind the scenes instead of `aptitude`*. Then I would run:

```
sudo ppa-purge -i ppa:hydr0g3n/qbittorrent-unstable
```

## Where It's Documented

For some reason, a few useful options for `ppa-purge` are not documented in [its manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ppa-purge.1.html), including `-i`. But you can get information about them by running `ppa-purge -h` (or just `ppa-purge` with no arguments):

```
ek@Del:~$ ppa-purge -h
Usage: sudo ppa-purge [options] <ppa:ppaowner>[/ppaname]

ppa-purge will reset all packages from a PPA to the standard
versions released for your distribution.

Options:
    -p [ppaname]        PPA name to be disabled (default: ppa)
    -s [host]       Repository server (default: ppa.launchpad.net)
    -d [distribution]   Override the default distribution choice.
    -y          Pass -y --force-yes to apt-get or -y to aptitude
    -i          Reverse preference of apt-get upon aptitude.
    -h          Display this help text

Example usage commands:
    sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
    will remove https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

    sudo ppa-purge -p xorg-testing sarvatt
    will remove https://launchpad.net/~sarvatt/+archive/xorg-testing

    sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
    will remove https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

Notice: If ppa-purge fails for some reason and you wish to try again,
(For example: you left synaptic open while attempting to run it) simply
uncomment the PPA from your sources, run apt-get update and try again.
```

"Reverse preference of apt-get upon aptitude" is a bit cryptic. By looking at [the relevant piece of the source code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1105934/) (`ppa-purge` is just a shell script, after all), we can see that this means that the default behavior is to prefer `aptitude` to `apt-get`, and the `-i` flag reverses this preference.

Comment: The last time when I tried ppa-purge, it did not remove packages that have been deleted from PPAs. Is that still the case?

Comment: @Lekensteyn Yes, I *believe* it is still the case that `ppa-purge` will *not* remove or downgrade packages that are no longer provided by the PPA being "purged." However, you may want to post a separate question about this, to get a more authoritative or well-documented answer.

Comment: If the repository is not a PPA hosted in Launchpad, but other non-standard repository, will ppa-purge work?

Comment: @Anwar I'm not positive if it will work, but you should be able to try by specifying the full repository URL instead of `ppa:username/path`. Also the PPA must be ENABLED before you attempt to purge it, even though the script immediately disables after updating the listing of packages to remove, it won't "find" already disabled  PPAs.

Comment: @Lekensteyn you can try using `aptitude search ~o` to find orphaned packages with no installation source if you need to purge something that was removed from a PPA (or was installed as a one off via `dpkg -i`).

Answer (score 7):

To at least find them, start by disabling the PPA's and run `apt-get update`. Then install `apt-show-versions`. Running `apt-show-versions | grep 'No available'` will then give you a list of all your installed packages that cannot be found in your configured repositories. With some command-line magic you can probably strip out the package names only and pass them to `apt-get remove`:

```
 for i in `apt-show-versions | grep 'No available' | cut -d' ' -f 1` ; do  sudo apt-get remove -y $i ; done
```

Note that this will go through the list returned from `apt-show-versions` and remove them one by one.  Depending on what it finds, this could uninstall something unintended due to dependencies, so check it first.

Comment: Sounds good, I will give it a try.

Comment: The upgrade process itself will also autodisable the PPAs, though I am pretty sure it won't go and remove all the left over packages.

Comment: @Jorge: I've indeed noticed that the PPA's are disabled (commented out), but it does not remove the packages. I think it's better to remove the packages before a new version from the Ubuntu repositories overwrite the files.

Comment: I've just tested this and it does not make a distinction between packages from the main repos and a PPA. In my case, it was the `libvpx0` package from the chromium-daily PPA. @enzotib's answer did show this package.

Comment: If you run `apt-show-versions` as non-root, it needs a `sudo apt-show-versions -i` to update it's cache and see changes from newly removed repositories / PPAs (otherwise it's only updated via a cron.daily job)

Comment: That does not downgrade packages that were upgraded by the PPA.

Answer (score 6):

Here is GUI ways to do so. Hope it would help for those who don't prefer CLI. The steps are simple and easy to follow.

1. Open [synaptic package manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/). If not installed then install it by:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install synaptic
   ```
2. When opened click on **Origin** button on down-left. It will list all the repositories on top-left side. Select the particular repository for which packages are to be removed. It will list all the packages under that repository. Click the first field i,e **S** or **Installed Version** field to show the installed packages first.
3. Now select all packages to remove.

   Tips to mark for removal:

   1. Select first package then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and again select the last package to select all. Then right click on the **square** box and select **mark for removal** or **mark for complete removal**.
   2. or Select any packages and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all. Then right click on the **square** box and chose **mark for removal** or **mark for complete removal.**

That's it. It will remove without any problem. I've also attached the image to make it more clear. Hope it would help. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found use of ppa-purge to be difficult.

Open Synaptic Package Manager under System, then select Settings, Repositories.

Remove the ones you don't want.

Done!

Comment: This removes only package sources, it does not remove the package from those sources.