# How to remove a repository and all it's installed programs?

Tags: 11.10, uninstall, repository, remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove all packages from a certain repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37531/how-do-i-remove-all-packages-from-a-certain-repository)

i have installed programs from the [nautilus-actions-extra](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/nautilus-actions-extra-pack-of-useful.html) and it cause a lot of problems so i want to remove this repository and all it's programs. so how to do that ???

Answer (score 2):

You can try ppa-purge.

For that, you need to already have the PPA to your system so that ppa-purge can analyse the packages installed from that PPA.

First of all, install ppa-purge by running the following command in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Then, run a command similar to this: `sudo ppa-purge nautilus-actions-extra`

After running ppa-purge, run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and the packages will be reverted to the default repository.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, in Synaptic (if you don't have Synaptic installed, run `sudo apt-get install synaptic`), you can filter available packages by origin, then click on the PPA containing the packages you wish to remove, then select them for removal or complete removal. Then in Software Sources you can remove the PPA and update package listings either by clicking on the "Reload" button in Synaptic or running `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal.