# Installing netflix-desktop

Tags: apt, software-installation

I installed `netflix-desktop` on my system running Ubuntu 12.04, and the app simply wouldn't launch. I removed it with these instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245258/uninstall-netflix-desktop?rq=1). I also ran these commands to clear out any settings: 
`rm -Rf ~/.wine-browser` and `rm -Rf ~/.netflix-desktop`.

I tried to reinstall with the instructions [here](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html), but I received the following error message:

```
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package netflix-desktop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  wine-browser-installer

E: Package 'netflix-desktop' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried installing wine-browser-installer, and that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot to add: I'm running 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you completely follow the steps in the installation instructions? Does the command `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ehoover*` output anything? This is just to make sure that the PPA was added successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try:
    `sudo apt-get purge netflix-desktop && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop`

This should (in theory) purge the entire netflix-desktop package and, since it sounds like you removed the ppa as well, add it back and reinstall the package. Omit `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio && sudo apt-get update &&` if you did not remove the ppa.

Instructions as per http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2084592-p-2.html and http://www.itworld.com/software/358908/install-netflix-ubuntu-1304

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
I removed `netflix-desktop` and purged the ppa. However, I also had to remove the following two files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ehoover-compholio-precise.list` and
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ehoover-compholio-precise.list.save`.

I had to remove these two files before I could correctly add the ppa and install `netflix-desktop` again.