# How do I remove Netflix-Desktop completely

Tags: firefox, wine, netflix

The script to install Netflix-Desktop downloaded everything needed except for Firefox. I keep trying to remove the program through "sudo apt-get remove --purge netflix-desktop". However, when I reinstall Netflix-desktop it runs through the script as if it's already downloaded everything. I've removed .wine-browser and /usr/share/netflix-desktop. When I have netflix-desktop installed, I can issue the command "netflix-desktop --showdebug" which will tell me that firefox.exe cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

On the install of ubuntu I'm using I don't have a full install but the person that answered before me is right, it is a PPA repository. On other installs of Ubuntu, and Ubuntu based distributions/flavors of Linux, this has successfully and totally removed the program and all remnants of it:

Run these commands one at a time:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ehoover/compholio
```

Answer (score 0):

I think NetFlix Desktop is from a PPA, so you would probably need ppa-purge?

But it sound like you are not trying to remove so much as re-install, in which case the info here might be helpful:

[Installing netflix-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334777/installing-netflix-desktop)

See also this bug report for suggestions specific to firefox/netflix-desktop install problems:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/netflix-desktop/+bug/1085511

Answer (score 0):

[to remove Netflix-Desktop completely](http://namhuy.net/1867/how-to-install-netflix-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-fedora.html)

```
# apt-get purge netflix-desktop
# apt-get autoremove
# rm -rf ~/.wine-browser
# rm -rf ~/.netflix-desktop
```