# How can I remove netflix-desktop to get the HD option back on Netflix?

Tags: wine, hd-video, pipelight, netflix-desktop

I installed pipelight using [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html) tutorial to watch Netflix using firefox on Ubuntu 14.04 and everything went well. After a couple of weeks and because of lagging problems watching HD stuff on Netflix, I decided to try Netflix-desktop.

The thing is that Netflix-desktop didn't solve my lagging problems and also took away the HD option from Netflix. I uninstalled Netflix-desktop using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350962/how-do-i-remove-netflix-desktop-completely) and, since I still didn't get the HD option back, I removed pipelight, wine, the .wine-pipelight folder and used autoremove for the packages left.

After reinstalling everything I still can't get the HD option back. Has anyone had this problem or know how to solve it?

Thank you.