# Can I convert my KDE Neon system to regular Ubuntu Bionic without reinstalling?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I have Neon. I've noticed certain packages are missing. `do-release-upgrade -d` doesn't work because "Upgrades to the development release are only available from the latest supported release.", but I can't switch because do-release-upgrade thinks I'm on the latest version. I actually only have the Xenial packages.

```
➜ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=neon
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="KDE neon User Edition 5.12"

➜ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep "deb http://ca.ar"
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

➜ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

➜ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

Can I turn my system into Bionic somehow instead of having broken Neon packages?

Comment: It's usually much easier to fix the problem you have instead of wandering off the trail in search of a different problem. Always fix your problems before release-upgrading - upgrades rarely fix package problems.

Comment: @user535733 I have a feeling my current package problems are related to the fact that I'm not on standard Ubuntu packages, though. Many packages (e.g. the desktop environments `lubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, off the top of my head) result in "but is not going to be installed" issues due to some obscure missing library packages with long names.

Answer (score 2):

## No, you cannot.

A release-upgrade is NOT like a clean-install.

Release-upgrades simply update your Ubuntu sources, and then pull updated packages from the new repositories. If you have *version conflicts*, *file conflicts*, *held broken packages*, or other common apt problems, a release-upgrade rarely fixes the problem. Indeed, it often makes the problem worse.

**If your system** can do a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` without any errors, **and** your system has no software from non-Ubuntu sources, **then** a release-upgrade is a fast, convenient way to migrate your system to the next release of Ubuntu.

**If you wish** to fix your system, then the usual method is to methodically [uninstall all software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37531/how-do-i-remove-all-packages-from-a-certain-repository) from each non-Ubuntu repository until the error messages cease. One PPA or non-Ubuntu repository at a time. Several apt commands (`policy`, 'depends', and 'rdepends') are very helpful tracing the dependencies and versions. Software in the Ubuntu repositories is versioned and tested to prevent those common apt errors, and usually does not need to be removed.

**If time is short, or fixing looks too difficult** then backup your data and do a clean install.