# missing packages in ubuntu when i try to install virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I was just trying to install virtualbox using

```
apt-get install virtualbox
```

And show in my ubuntu:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 perl-base : Breaks: debconf (< 1.5.61) but 1.5.58ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Breaks: debconf:i386 (< 1.5.61)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

why happen and how i can solve it??

sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release i386 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# Kali linux repositories | Added by Katoolin
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free**
```

Comment: Can you share your sources.list and any third party repositories or PPAs you have?

Comment: For the future - please [edit] your qeustion to add information; do not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have Kali in your sources list. If we look up debconf for Xenial (16.04), the [latest version is 1.5.58ubuntu1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/debconf) at the time of this writing. You have a newer debconf, probably from kali.

Kali's [Packages list](https://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/binary-amd64/Packages) indicates that the latest version of debconf in kali is 1.5.66.

You probably also have `perl-base` from kali repository. `perl-base` is listed as breaking `debconf` << 1.5.61.

The problem is that you have multiple repositories with mutually exclusive dependencies - which **will** create problems. Kalis repositories is supposed to provide the whole system, not only parts of it.

You may have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37531/how-do-i-remove-all-packages-from-a-certain-repository) which discusses how to remove all packages from a particular repository, so that you can remove all Kali packages from your system, which should enable you to install virtualbox.