# Packages from repositories which has been disabled

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I just realized that in Ubuntu, if I remove (="disable") a repository, its installed packages remain installed!
For example `sudo add-apt-repository --remove multiverse`.

The status of this "stray" packages is **unclear**.

Will they be subject to `apt-get dist-upgrade` or `apt-get upgrade`?
Will they be subject to `apt-get --purge autoremove`?
Will they be subject to `apt-get clean` or any other `apt-get` command?

Maybe these packages just remain in some frezed state, and are becoming more and more outdated?
There is no simple command line way to even point out them, or get rid of them? Only a quite complicated (and maybe slow), like https://askubuntu.com/a/37536/851189 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can point them out thusly:

```
for i in $( dpkg -l | grep -E '^ii' | awk '{print $2}' ) ; \
do apt show -a "$i" 2>/dev/null  | grep -E 'Package:|APT-Sources'; done
```

You may have to adjust the `grep -E '^ii'` to pick the packages you want out of `dpkg -l`.

Read `man apt`, and look at the output of `apt show <packagename>` without the filtering.